# JavaScript/jQuery: how to get parameters with their values from .attr("action")?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form rendered in Ruby On Rails, looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag myaction_path(item_id: item.id), 
                            { class: 'myaction', 
                                id: "myaction_#{item.id}", 
                                method: :get, 
                                remote: true } do %>
```

and I process the data in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $(".myaction").submit(function(event){  
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log($(this).attr("action"));
    ...
```

`console.log($(this).attr("action"));` returns `/app/myaction?item_id=5528`.

I need the `item_id` as a key to access other items in the form. Is there any elegant way to fetch it from `$(this).attr("action")` or do I need to manually parse the string (`/app/myaction?item_id=5528`)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the query string from the form action. You have to parse it manually.

```
let str = $(this).attr("action");

function parseQueryString(str) {
  let query = str.split("?");
  if (query.length > 1) {
    let item = query[1].split("=");
    return item[1] ? item[1] : "";
  }
}

let result = parseQueryString(str);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the item_id in the hidden input field.
Or else if you want to parse the item_id or any other field from the action then you can use below js function:

```js
function parseURL(url) {
    var searchObject = {}
    let queries = new URL(url).search.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&');
    for( i = 0; i < queries.length; i++ ) {
        split = queries[i].split('=');
        searchObject[split[0]] = split[1];
    }
    return searchObject;
}
```